# Traveling to New Zealand for 2 weeks - Verizon Phone and what to do?

Tags: cellphones, new-zealand

I have an iPhone 5S with Verizon and want to know the best way to have a mobile phone while there without incurring a massive Verizon bill.  I would like to have data and voice, but I can settle for voice only and use wifi when it's free.  Can I buy a SIM card and change it out or should I buy a prepaid phone for the 2 weeks or "rent" one from Verizon (again expensive probably)?

Comment: Is your phone unlocked ?

Comment: Why would you rent a phone from Verizon? Wouldn't you want to rent one in NZ?

Answer (score 1):

You have many options to get a travel SIM in NZ, make sure your phone is unlocked. Apple allows this so check with Verizon before you go.
To check if your phone can work on NZ networks, [this](https://www.apple.com/iphone/LTE/) page says the A1530 version of the iPhone 5s works with the carriers listed. You can find that info on the back of the phone

[Vodafone NZ](http://www.vodafone.co.nz/travel-sim/): 3GB / 200min / 200txt (49$) (it doesn't say anywhere on their page but I assume they sell nano SIM as they already sell iPhones)

[2degrees](https://www.2degreesmobile.co.nz/mobile/prepay/)  has a prepaid option for data only (20$ for 1GB, 10$ for 300) but you need to unsubscribe before leaving otherwise it auto renews at the end of the month. They have nano SIMs for iPhones

[Spark NZ](http://www.spark.co.nz/help/mobile-data/plans-services/) (formerly NZ Telecom) also has prepaid monthly options (data only, or voice and text), but their terms are less clear than the others, you'll probably need to unsubscribe before leaving as with 2degrees.

Comment: Do Verizon phones even work in NZ? Verizon, last I knew, was CDMA, and practically the entire rest of the world uses GSM.  Or maybe the 5s supports both?

Comment: @Flimzy good catch ! Updated

Comment: @Flimzy Verizon uses CDMA but the iPhone 5s is also able to use GSM.